# script not executing on ubuntu no file or directory. Hyperledger explorer

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal, hyperledger

My Hyperledger explorer script is not executing in the terminal, gives a "no such file or directory error" even though it is clearly in the directory.

I list all the files in the directory (notice start.sh is in there)

`ubuntu@jb-hyperledger:~/bludev/blockchain-explorer$ ls
app          CONTRIBUTING.md  main.js          node_modules       README.md
client       LICENSE          MAINTAINERS.rst  package.json       start.sh`

I then get this error when i try to execute

`ubuntu@jb-hyperledger:~/bludev/blockchain-explorer$ ./start.sh
-bash: ./start.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

please assist, thank you

Comment: `^M` = CR see CRLF, dos2unix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, the answer was indeed to do

```
dos2unix start.sh
```

thanks